# If some events with user_id and others only with user_pseudo_id GA4 will be able to build a funnel?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

Such a case:

1. Users come from an external source to my site **example.com** . At this moment I don't have a permanent `user_id`, GA sets a `user_pseudo_id`
2. Then users log in to **auth.example.com** and at this moment there is still no me there is no permanent `user_id`, only `user_pseudo_id` (I assume the same as in the previous step, because the domain has not changed)
3. After authorization, there is a redirect to **dash.example.com**, here I set the persistent `user_id` for the user and send all events in GA4 with this `user_id`, but there is also a `user_pseudo_id` (the same as in the previous steps)

In this case when I'll build [a funnel](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9327974?hl=en), how GA4 will connect events that do not have a `user_id`, but only `user_pseudo_id`, and events that have `user_id` and `user_pseudo_id`. Will it be able to understand that these events are from one user to build the funnel correctly. Or does GA divide users after setting `user_id` (on the step3 in the case)?

I tried to build a funnel (example.com => auth.example.com => dash.example.com), but some of the events in it are lost.